# How can I generate cyclic whole number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, algorithms

My goal was to create a function that would generate number from 1->N->1. 1 2 3 4 3 2 1.

Easiest approach I was going for was create a function where using cosine i'd generate integers, and where x -> 2N.

So if N is 4, then x would go upto 2x4 = 8.

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

then output of ƒ would be

1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1

or

1 2 3 4 3 2 1

either would have been great.

Comment: What you want is called a triangle wave. It differs from a sinusoid, which cannot work alone for large $N$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave#/media/File:Waveforms.svg

Comment: what kind of function are you looking for ? a continuous one or a discrete one (with floor, sign, etc.) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{2(N-1)}\pi\arcsin\left(\sin\left(\pi\frac{x-1}{2(N-1)}\right)\right)+1.$$

Comment: Thanks I think this is getting somewhere, I'm sure answer is there somewhere in variables there.. https://ibb.co/JdNRNS7 I tried for 3 and it got there but after find tuning other parameters

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: what is wrong with my answer ?

Comment: nothing, i have to get it to work so it goes like this : n = 3, if x= 0,1,2,3,4,5 then y = 0,1,2,2,1,0. I got it to work for some specific n but had to tune some variables. But I do think this is it. Much thanks

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: you said you started from $1$, not from $0$ !

Answer (score 2):

If $n$ is the length of a series of $1$s, then
$\space(111\cdots)^2=(123\cdots n\cdots 321)\space$ for $n$ ones.

$$1^2=1\quad11^2=121\quad 111^2=12321\quad 1111^2=1234321\quad \cdots$$

This will work for any $n$ provided the base is at least $n+1$.